# Force new Dropbox api refresh token

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I have experienced accidentally deleting the refresh token to the Dropbox API and when I try to get a new, only an access token is returned.

```py
def generate_refresh_token():
    env = os.environ

    auth_flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(
        env["DROPBOX_APP_KEY"],
        env["DROPBOX_APP_SECRET"],
        token_access_type="offline",
    )

    authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
    print(f"1. Go to: {authorize_url}")
    print('2. Login with the dropbox service account!\nClick "Allow" (you might have to log in first).')
    print("3. Copy the authorization code.")
    auth_code = input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

    oauth_result = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
    print("[green]Successfully connected to Dropbox[/green]")
    if oauth_result.refresh_token:
            print(f"[green]Refresh token: <{oauth_result.refresh_token}>[/green]")
    else:
            print(f"[red] No refresh token recieved! [/ref]")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  generate_refresh_token()
```

where the returned `oauth_result` has no refresh token

```
──────────────────────── <class 'dropbox.oauth.OAuth2FlowNoRedirectResult'> ────────────────────────╮
│ Authorization information for an OAuth2Flow performed with no redirect.                            │
│                                                                                                    │
│ ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │ OAuth2FlowNoRedirectResult(sl.BH3bS7tvBehDQLnMJ0mYYzTAMC3jqhogm8_OK0Hmg5E7-ShZYzMCxaZ4sTNUWM44 │ │
│ │ gyIk06YnQl4uncEor0TAvJyDVb0EQyGZO8mm-UY93l4FL8GT-TRssd43Pb3z768-VC55m4JI,                      │ │
│ │ dbid:AACM6APiewEZWXE0BUtmiqKBaWFwUd3n9ks, 1243637441, , 2022-05-18 17:00:16.906272,            │ │
│ │ account_info.read files.content.read files.content.write files.metadata.read sharing.read      │ │
│ │ sharing.write)                                                                                 │ │
│ ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                                                    │
│  access_token = 'sl.BH3bS7tvBehDQLnMJ0mYYzTAMC3jqhogm8_OK0Hmg5E7-ShZYzMCxaZ4sTNUWM44gyIk06YnQl4un… │
│    account_id = 'dbid:AACM6APiewEZWXE0BUtmiqKBaWFwUd3n9ks'                                         │
│    expires_at = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 18, 17, 0, 16, 906272)                                  │
│ refresh_token = ''                                                                                 │
│         scope = 'account_info.read files.content.read files.content.write files.metadata.read      │
│                 sharing.read sharing.write'                                                        │
│       user_id = '1243637441'                                                                       │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Is there a way to force Dropbox to return a new refresh token for the same user without having to create a new application?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a new refresh token for a user, the user does need to process the OAuth app authorization, with `token_access_type="offline"`, as shown here. It is not necessary to create a new application entirely.

Is this the exact code you're running? The code you shared here appears correct, and does work and print out a refresh token for me when I run it (plugging in an app key/secret).

Comment: Yes, this is the exact code. I get the refresh token the first time for an application, but the following calls will not return a refresh token, as described in the text

Comment: By "the following calls", do you mean you're calling the same `generate_refresh_token` method repeatedly? That would involve manual user interaction, but should result in a new refresh token each time. You don't need to call that multiple times per user though. Refresh tokens don't expire automatically so you should store and re-use them repeatedly.

Comment: The premise is that I lost the refresh token and I don't get a refresh token when using the function again.